# My gulp.js file is not updating my css on the browser

Tags: javascript, css, less, gulp-watch, browser-sync

I am using a gulp.js file to convert my less code to css and then update the website automatically on save using BrowserSync however, when I save the file no changes have been made. the code for my gulp.js file is below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
                    less = require('gulp-less'),
                    uglifycss = require("gulp-uglifycss"),
                    path = require('path'),
                    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
                    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
                    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
                    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
                    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
                    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
                    imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize'),
                    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
                    changed = require("gulp-changed"),
                    plumber = require("gulp-plumber"),
                    cmq = require('gulp-combine-media-queries');


            var run = require('gulp-run');

            //gulp.src(['js/**/*.js', '!js/**/*.min.js'])

            gulp.task('default', function () {


                 var devProxy = "mywebsite.dev.chand.co";
            // } 

            browserSync({
                    proxy: devProxy,
                    files: "library/css/*.css"
                });

            //gulp.watch('./library/less/**/*.less', ['compile-css']);

            gulp.watch('./library/less/**/*.less', ['compile-css']);

            gulp.watch(['./library/js/*.js', '!./library/js/main-built.js'], ['javascript']);

            });



            gulp.task('javascript', function() {
             gulp.src(['./library/js/*.js','./library/js/components/*.js', '!./library/js/main-built.js',  '!./library/js/cf7.js'])     // ignore vendor stuff
             .pipe(plumber())    
             .pipe(jshint())
             .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));

            //    gulp.src(['./library/js/**/*.js', '!./library/js/require.js'])    
               //.pipe(uglify())
            //     .pipe(gulp.dest('library/dist/js'));


            run('r.js -o build.js').exec();
            });


            gulp.task('compile-css', function () {
            gulp.src('./library/less/main.less')
                        .pipe(plumber())    
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        //.pipe(uglifycss())
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));



            gulp.src('./library/less/admin.less')
                        .pipe(plumber())    
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        //.pipe(uglifycss())
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));

            gulp.src('./library/less/editor-style.less')
                        .pipe(plumber())    
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        //.pipe(uglifycss())
                        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));


            gulp.src('./library/less/style-bootstrap.less')
                        .pipe(plumber())    
                        //.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        //.pipe(uglifycss())

                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));

            return; 

            });

            gulp.task('dist-css', function () {
            gulp.src('./library/less/main.less')
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        .pipe(cmq({
                          log: true
                        }))
                        .pipe(uglifycss())
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));




            gulp.src('./library/less/admin.less')
                        //.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        .pipe(uglifycss())
                        //.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));

            gulp.src('./library/less/editor-style.less')
                        //.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                        .pipe(less())
                        .pipe(autoprefixer())
                        .pipe(uglifycss())
                        //.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
                        .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));



            });




            gulp.task('resize-images', function () {

            // this doesn't happen automatically, because it's a bit intensive, it should be done when we need.

            var originalName;

             gulp.src("images/src/**/*.{jpg,png}")
            .pipe(changed("images/dist"))


            // This isn't ideal, but it'll work fine
            // Make sure that you go BIGGEST FIRST because of piping

            // Need to change renaming to the wordpress convention

            // need to specify heights?

            // need to do lossless optimisation

            // remember to set new name as well as new size for each resize.
            .pipe(imageResize({ 
                imageMagick : true,
                width : 200
            }))
            .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                originalName = path.basename;
                path.basename = originalName + "-200";        
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("images/dist"))


            .pipe(imageResize({ 
                imageMagick : true,
                width : 100
            }))
            .pipe(rename(function (path) {
                path.basename = originalName + "-100";        
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("images/dist"));

            });
```

Comment: First of all, you could make the code a whole lot simpeler. Gulp.src can glob (see: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)
     `return gulp.src('./library/less/{main, admin,editor-style, style-bootstrap}.less')
       .pipe(plumber())    
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(less())
       .pipe(autoprefixer())
       //.pipe(uglifycss())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./library/css/'));`
Do you mean that the files are not updated, or that the they were never written to the expected location?

Comment: @Rik - Thanks, I will clean it up. When i update the less file, I can see it has changed in the CSS but it does not update my page CSS although its reloading the page soon as I make a change.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your less task is working, and your css is moved to the correct location, but on a refresh it is not loaded in the browser.
This sounds like a caching problem in the browser. What happens if yo mannually reload (Ctrl+F5)? Does it refresh the css then, because then it is definitly a caching problem.

Comment: I added a possible solution for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are having a caching problem I read more about this for css + browsersync. 
[this post](https://github.com/BrowserSync/gulp-browser-sync/issues/37) might help you.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907196/browser-sync-reloading-but-css-not-changing-with-less-and-gulp) could be your solution then.

move your watch to a seperate task

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function(){
    gulp.watch('./library/less/**/*.less', ['compile-css']);
    gulp.watch('./library/css/**/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

and let it depend on `browser-sync`

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    var devProxy = "mywebsite.dev.chand.co";
    browserSync({
        proxy: devProxy,
        files: "library/css/*.css"
    });
});
```

And then change `default` to

```
gulp.task('default', 'watch');
```

read more about reloading + browserSync [here](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/#gulp-sass-css)

Comment: thanks very much for this. I will try this solution when I get to work tomorrow. Just a thought could it be the source maps not updating?

Comment: I doubt that. Source maps are merely for debugging purposes. In your snippet they are also commented, but don't know if you commented it to see if it would help.

Comment: I've tried this solution but it still dosent seem to update the css on the page

Comment: Have you tried reloading th epage manually with Ctrl+F5, and do you see the changes then?

Comment: Hi Rik, I've reloaded the page manually as well with Ctrl+F5 no luck though still :(

Comment: That means it probably isn't a caching problem. But when you change a file in your `./library/less/` folder, this gets recompiled and ends up in your `./library/css/` folder? 
And your html page also looks at files in your `./library/css/` folder?

Comment: Hi Rik that is correct. when i press save browser Sync loads the html page but dosent update the styles, so its loading the right HTML and compiling the right less file to CSS but just not updating. I dont know what could be the issue, my head is going nuts

Comment: Hi, I added an example to [my github](https://github.com/hwdegroot/browsersync-example) . Take a look at this, because that will work fine. 
You can use this maybe as a base. I actually made the number of css file dynamic, and inject them into the html page with `gulp-inject`. Hope this will get you going.

Comment: this is working now. For some reason it started to update. Thanks Rik for all your help and efforts!

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth trying to delete your compressed CSS and JavaScript files manually.

`rm -f web/css/compressed/style.css` for example

...and then trying a `gulp build` again.